# Time stamp comparison in spark scala is returning incorrect values

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I am comparing 2 timestamp columns in my dataset/dataframe and generating a new column but its giving incorrect value

```
dateField1 = 2021-01-12 18:58:37.725
dateField2 = 2021-01-12 18:00:00

df = df.withColumn("Flag",when($"dateField1" >= $"dateField2",true).otherwise(false))
```

In the above, ideally it should be true but new column flag has the value of **false**.

Comment: not reproducible. Please show the complete code you used and print out the dataframe

Comment: please add the sample data.

Comment: The sample data makes no sense. Strings are not wrapped in quotes. Also they are supposed to be columns, not  strings.

Comment: If the question, as posted, has no answer because the problem is caused elsewhere in the code base, then please consider deleting the question. It can serve no useful purpose being archived here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create the sample input based on the data in the question and implemented that as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(("2021-01-12 18:58:37.725","2021-01-12 18:00:00")).toDF("Date1","Date2")
val df1 = df.withColumn("Date1",$"Date1".cast("Timestamp")).withColumn("Date2",$"Date2".cast("Timestamp"))
val df2 = df1.withColumn("Flag",when($"Date1" >= $"Date2",true).otherwise(false))
display(df2)  // databricks output style
```

You can see the output as below :

[image]

Comment: Thank you . Problem is this is inconsistent , when I run the same values outside of the dataset , its retuning true but inside the scala app, its returning false.  Please do note . its not happening for all the records only for around 5-6 rows  and I am confused on why its returning correctly for 98% of the records not for the 2% of them